# Почему гит воспринимает файлы как измененные?

Tags: git, github

С чем это связано? При изменении одного файла он начал воспринимать и другие как измененные

[image: картинка]

Comment: поменялись пермиссии на файлы?

Comment: Кто-то зачем-то поменял им права доступа (циферки справа)

Comment: @AlexeyTen, а как с этим быть? Я работа из под мака и + использую докер

Comment: Нашел! Спасибо за подсказку! Ответ: git config core.filemode false